# Password authentication error with Python Fabric

Tags: python, python-3.x, fabric

I'm trying to ssh to some hosts with fabric but I get an authentication error, though the username and passwords of my routers are admin/admin.

```
g = ThreadingGroup('192.168.255.68', '192.168.254.108', user='admin', port=22, connect_kwargs={'password': 'admin'})    
g.run('version')

{<Connection host=192.168.255.68 user=admin>: AuthenticationException('Authentication failed.'), <Connection host=192.168.254.108 user=admin>: AuthenticationException('Authentication failed.')}
```

With debug enabled I see:

```
    DEBUG:2022-02-21 03:27:12,044:Trying discovered key b'.......4b7dc25cb5d87a6a' in /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
    DEBUG:2022-02-21 03:27:12,087:userauth is OK
    INFO:2022-02-21 03:27:12,145:Authentication (publickey) failed.
    DEBUG:2022-02-21 03:27:12,186:EOF in transport thread
    DEBUG:2022-02-21 03:27:12,187:Encountered exception AuthenticationException('Authentication failed.') in thread for 'thread_worker'
```

Why is it even looking at id_rsa key, when I am specifically asking to authenticate with a password?

Comment: Figured it out by using "look_for_keys:False" inside connect_kwargs, no mentioning of this parameter in offical fabric doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out by using "look_for_keys:False" inside connect_kwargs